# How can I connect the flashing light circuit from an alarm into the main vehicle lighting on a Toyota Hiace van?

Tags: alarm

I have installed a Uniden VX2600 car alarm into my 1993 toyota hiace super custom.

[image]

The only thing left is to connect the parklight wires from the alarm to the actual vehicle parklights or indicators.

[image]

My question is, how can I connect these alarm lighting wires into either the main vehicle lighting so that the alarm causes the vehicles lights to flash?
It doesn't have to be the parklights specifically any of these would be ok

- the hazard lights
- the indicator lights
- the parklights

#### What I have tried so far

I have tried to find an OEM signal wire (e.g. from the hazard light switch  or the main light switch stalk behind the steering wheel) that I could just apply the wires from the alarm to - with a diode to prevent current bleed back into the main electrical system - but I can't find anything that causes the vehicle lights to switch on and off.

I think I could connect directly to the light bulb holders themselves  (from  inside the park or indicator lights lens covers) would this work? if so would

- I need to supply to each light individually - or just one and the current will spread to the rest?
- can I cause damage to the rest of the electrical system if I just connect **12v +ve** from the alarm light output into the light bulbs?

---

Here is the [Uniden VX2600 complete alarm wiring diagram](http://s3.amazonaws.com/f01.justanswer.com/JACUSTOMERfm1fcwsb/2010-08-27_225411_VS1600XR.jpg)

Comment: wouldn't the alarm module provide the flash? if so you just tap both left and right signal wires from the multifunction switch.

Comment: @ben yes the alarm pulses/flashes the 12v signal through the wires so, yes if you connected the wire to the positive of  light bulb it would flash. When you say multifunction switch, do you mean the stalk behind the steering wheel? Ive followed and even cut those wires and they still dont seem to affect the lights

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best place to make this change would be at the fuse box using a separate fuse. You will need a wiring diagram for your vehicle to identify the wires going from the fuse box exclusively to the bulbs.

"I need to supply to each light individually - or just one and the current will spread to the rest?" Each bulb needs to receive current from its positive wire. Get a wiring diagram.

"can I cause damage to the rest of the electrical system if I just connect 12v +ve from the alarm light output into the light bulbs?" No. The bulbs are controlled by mechanical relays, so there is no connection to the rest of the system when the relay is off. When the relay is on,the potential is 12v throughout this wire already. There will be no electrical bleed.

This all assumes you splice into the correct wires. Seriously, I have done this for years and I would never gamble splicing any wire without a wiring diagram to positively identify what I am splicing into, what that is connected to, etc.

Comment: great advice thanks. I've tried to find a wiring diagram without success. Im guessing otherwise I will have to attach directly to the bulb holder itself inside the lense cover . That way at least Ill know what im connecting to?

Comment: Unfortunately, I know nothing about the Hiace so it's hard for me to say anything- so I

Answer (score 1):

recently... i have done this before. What i'm doing is... i connect directly to left/right respectively. one wire connect to left signal and another one to to right signal. For simple car, i think should be no problem. My car so far so good.

Comment: thanks, so you mean you remove the light/lens cover and then connect the wire into the bulb holder?